# Why can't I use HashSet<string> to implement an IEnumerable<string> interface property?

Tags: c#, interface, hashset

I was wondering why can't I use `HashSet<string>` to implement an `IEnumerable<string>` interface property ?

The code below gives me a compile error with the following error;

> 'Lookups' does not implement interface member 'ILookups.LastNames'.
>   'Lookups.LastNames' cannot implement 'ILookups.LastNames' because it
>   does not have the matching return type of
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'.

```
public interface ILookups
{
    IEnumerable<string> FirstNames { get; set; }
    IEnumerable<string> LastNames { get; set; }
    IEnumerable<string> Companies { get; set; }
}

public class Lookups : ILookups
{
    public HashSet<string> FirstNames { get; set; }
    public HashSet<string> LastNames { get; set; }
    public HashSet<string> Companies { get; set; }
}
```

According to Resharper, this is the constructor signature for `HashSet`; ...

```
// Type: System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1
// Assembly: System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
// Assembly location: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Core.dll
...
  /// <summary>
  /// Represents a set of values.
  /// </summary>
  /// <typeparam name="T">The type of elements in the hash set.</typeparam>
  [DebuggerDisplay("Count = {Count}")]
  [DebuggerTypeProxy(typeof (HashSetDebugView<>))]
  [__DynamicallyInvokable]
  [Serializable]
  [HostProtection(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, MayLeakOnAbort = true)]
  public class HashSet<T> : ISerializable, 
      IDeserializationCallback, ISet<T>, 
      ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable
  {
```

...and it looks like it definitely implements `IEnumerable<T>` huh! This is not critical, just annoying as the workaround is just lengthy and feels like a broken feature of the language and very er..Java-ish? (he he!). (I will post the work around here later as soon as it's done in case I've missed a trick). If anyone has an answer or a better way to do this, or why this is like this, that would be most appreciated?

txs,

Alan

UPDATE:1.1.15 1 day after most of the comments were written, so please take with a pinch of salt.

re: re: "You can't implement a property that's declared to return A with another one that returns B even when B inherits/implements A."  I don't believe this is entirely correct, as the following code compiles perfectly ok; doh!

```
 void Main()
{
    var r = new PersonRepo();
    Console.WriteLine(r.GetPerson(2).Name);
}

public class PersonRepo : IPersonRepo
{
    public Person GetPerson(int id)
    {
        var m = new Manager()
        { 
            Department = "department" + id.ToString(), 
            Name = "Name " + id.ToString()
        };
        return m;
    }
}

public interface IPersonRepo
{
    Person GetPerson(int id);
}

public class Person 
{
    public string Name { get; set;}
}

public class Manager : Person
{
    public string Department { get; set; }
}
```

I've just seen my mistake, the code above will not compile if you change `Person GetPerson(int id)` to `Manager GetPerson(int id)` you will get a compile error, which actually does make sense! Ok, I think this is done and dusted! ;-D

Comment: It tells you exactly why in the error message that you included in your question: `because it does not have the matching return type of System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable.`

Comment: Actually, Java does allow this.

Comment: ha ha! that's brilliant, apologies to the Java devs! nice one.

Comment: @kyle has a good point in the comments to the answer below, saying that the interface shouldn't have had the setters. Much of the discussion has been around the fact that the setters are there. Remove the setter from the interface and the code more accurately reflects the intent of my question, but fundamentally would be a brand new question, so just referring to Kyle's comment here. Thanks everyone for the quick and detailed replied, awesome stuff.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To implement interface member signature must be exactly the same as declared in interface. You can't implement a property that's declared to return `A` with another one that returns `B` even when `B` inherits/implements `A`.

You can implement that member expliticly and route it to your property:

```
public class Lookups : ILookups
{
    public HashSet<string> FirstNames { get; set; }

    IEnumerable<string> ILookups.FirstNames { get { return this.FirstNames; } }
}
```

Why is that required? Consider following code:

```
var lookups = (ILookups)new Lookups();
// assigning List<string> to ILookups.FirstNames, which is IEnumerable<string>
lookups.FirstNames = new List<string>();
```

How would you like this to be solved? It's totally valid code, but with your `Lookups` implementation you've just assigned `List<string>` to `HashSet<string>`! It doesn't matter for methods and/or getter-only properties, but maybe just for sake of consistency?

Comment: Eeeeek! that's horrendous! Ok, granted, I realise that it's quite a compact solution for C#, and I really appreciate the prompt and accurate response. The "shreek" from me, is me realising that my love child C# is broken! sob. (he says, thumbing whistfully through F# Functional programming. Hmmm, time to move onto a language where all your code are belong to you, and every line of code expresses intent. It seems so wrong to have to write lines of code, simply because the compiler can't infer what to do. )

Comment: The HashSet-typed setter doesn't implement the IEnumerable-typed setter interface! The IEnumerable setter allows setting a List or Dictionary or anything, but the HashSet type doesn't support that. It makes perfect sense that interfaces require a 100% matching implementation.

Comment: Is it wrong for me to want to interpret that if something requires `IList`, that intent is that you are free to use anything that implements `IList`? Imagine if a method signatures were also this strict? `public string TestIt(IList<string> foo)` would not be able to take a `List of string`!

Comment: Returning value and implementing/overriding members are two completely different things.

Comment: sure, understood. (No argument from me.) I'm simply commiserating that the answer means that the language is a bit borked in my opinion. I think it's dumb because there's no practical benefit from forcing the language to be so verbose and not simply do what most people would expect it to. Compiler could easily add in the appropriate conversion and casting under the hood.

Comment: @snowcode You'd have a point about the language being broken if your properties only had getters, but your example has both getters *and* setters.  So what you're trying to do doesn't make sense.  Look at it this way: your interface says that there's a property that can be *set* to any implementation of `IEnumerable<string>`, but your implementation only allows the property to be set to `HashSet<string>`, so you're not fulfilling the interface contract!

Comment: Hi @Kyle, thanks for that comment, you beat me to it! Yes, the setters should not be in the interface. I'm so used to adding them to most POCO's so that serialisers can do their thing, ...bad habit I know. My comment saying the language is Borked applies (in hindsight) to when the interface only has getters. Thanks for your comment, I don't feel so stupid. ;-D